# Using bottom navigator icons and icons in page to navigate to a new screen: Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app and in it I have the bottom navigator icons that lead to different screens of the app.

At the same time I want to have icons in the page that lead to the same screen, while showing the bottom navigator icons still, but I can't seem to find my way around it.

On clicking on the in-page icons, I'm led to a new screen but without the bottom navigator icons.

Answer (score 0):

Try making list of pages you want to navigate

```
int _selectedIndex = 0; //selected page index

 List pages=[
    Page1(),//current home page
    Page2(),
    Page3()
  ];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

add this inside scaffold body

```
 body :_selectedIndex != 0 ? pages[_selectedIndex] :(your body widget)
```

and inside bottom navigation bar set

```
bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(
     
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: _onItemTapped
    
    )
```